# How does heroku know if you are the one who bought the domain name?

Tags: heroku, dns

I am trying to use a custom domain name in Heroku. So I was following the general directions and I had a question about it.

So I want to get rid of the herokuapp.com in example.herokuapp.com, which requires that I buy the example.com domain name.

It says in the first step "Confirm that you own the custom domain name. If not, you can buy one with a domain registration service."

How does heroku know that I bought example.com in the domain registration service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at your Herokuapp.com dashboard, for your particular app, you'll find that heroku has issued you a specific domain name. Something like `some-custom-string.herokudns.com`. Notice that this is `herokuDNS.com` which is different from `herokuapp.com` (herokuapp.com is used to access your website publicly). Only you have access to this custom dns string.

When you buy a domain name from a registrar, it'll usually also provide a DNS server. You'll then add a CNAME record in your DNS settings to point to your heroku provided `some-custom-string.herokudns.com` url. Since only you've access to your DNS server settings, if Heroku finds that the cname entry is present in your DNS records, it'll be a confirmation that you own the domain. The steps to do this are described [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains).

Comment: Thank you! After I buy the domain name, I just have to follow the steps?

Comment: Yeah, you just have to edit the DNS records as shown on the link I added.